# Calling a derived class method from the parent class' same method

Tags: c++, object, networking, polymorphism, derived-class

My problem goes as follow: I am writing an extensible communication protocol between a server and a client. The objects needed to be transferred are using the [command design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Here is the class format:

```cpp
class command {

  public:
    using id = uint8_t;
    using buffer = std::vector<char>;

    enum command_t: id {a_command, another_command};

    command() = delete;
    command(id id): id_(id) {}

    static command* unserialize(buffer);
    virtual buffer const serialize() const = 0;

    virtual void execute() = 0;

  protected:
    /* Not possible, see further where I explain. Keeping it here for
       my example */
    virtual static command* do_unserialize(buffer::iterator, buffer::iterator) = 0;
    id id_;

};

class a_command;
class another_command;
```

Every command will be a subclass of `command`. A `command_t` id will be associated with every command. In the example above, `a_command` and `another_command` would have a respective class too.

`command::serialize` is implemented in the derived classes. What it does is it writes all the needed informations of the class in a byte array and returns it. Of course, the same thing goes for the protected `command::do_unserialize` - it takes a byte array and converts it to a command **of the right type**. But here is the problem:

The first byte of the buffer will **always** be the `command::id` associated with the good subclass.
When the server/client will receive data, it will read the command ID and then it needs to be able to unserialize it to *the right command type*. This is why it will need to call the static function `command::unserialize` and not one of the subclasses' `do_unserialize`.

---

A quick and dirty fix would be a `command::unserialize` looking like this:

```cpp
command* command::unserialize(buffer b) {

    auto it{b.begin()};

    command::id const id{*it++};

    switch(static_cast<command::command_t>(id)) {
        case command::command_t::a_command:
            return a_command::do_unserialize(it, b.end());
        case command::command_t::another_command:
            return another_command::do_unserialize(it, b.end());
        default: 
            throw std::invalid_argument("command::unserialize: unknown command ID");
    }   
}
```

*** Actually not even, you cannot have a virtual static member function. So I have no idea how it could be implemented.

Even if it worked, it is not really fun, because it implies having to duplicate a line of code
for every new command created.

EDIT: A working example would be to move `do_unserialize` to the subclass constructor and return a pointer to the newly created object.

```cpp
class derived_command: public command {
  public:
    derived_command(buffer::iterator beg, buffer::iterator end) {
        // do_unserialize logic
    }
};

// unserialize
switch (id) {
    case command::command_t::derived_class: return new derived_class(b.begin(), b.end());
}
// ...
```

---

My question thus goes like this: Is there a way to dynamically link new commands only from the `command::id` field? A way to deduce the subclass to use from its ID? Else, is my design flawed? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thank you!

Comment: You should definitely revise your design. `static` function can never be virtual/pure virtual.

Comment: I know, I put it here because it was the only way I could show an example that explains well what I'm trying to achieve. As I said, this is not the way I want it to be done, I am looking for a better (in that case *working) way

Comment: You could make something like a factory method that, given the ID, would call the proper unserialize function.  If you don't want to have a big switch statement to do that, you can include a registration function where the different classes would pass in their IDs and a pointer to the function to call to do the unseralization for that type.

Comment: I would separate `command` to `command` and `parser`. `parser` will have a `parse_command` member that will parse the command id from the buffer and return an instance of the concrete command class (Of course it's like factory with more flexibility in parsing algorithms). Your `command` will never have to work with the buffer, instead the `parser` will handle that for you.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I think I could go for a factory, I hadn't thought about it. However, without adding anything, I think a simpler way would be to just do as I added in my edit (ie buffer constructors). A factory would definetely be more flexible though